# Weather in Transylvania, Romania in October

Tags: weather-and-climate, romania

I'm planning a trip to Transylvania in Romania at the October first.
I was thinking of renting a car and doing mostly 1 day trips (or possibly two days trip with proximation to the car, for example Făgăraș mountains).

How problematic would it be weather-wise? Does it rain in the beginning of October? If it rains would it rain for 10 days in a row? Would rain mean I wouldn't be able to travel \ track \ trail in nature?

Comment: Romania is a large area with varied geography.  It has mountains, highlands, valleys, plains and seaside.  The weather is not the same everywhere.  You will need to tell us where you are going specifically.

Comment: planning to go to transylvania

Comment: Yes, it is conceivable that it could rain for a week, but it is not particularly likely.  The weather cools quickly in October, the beginning can be quite warm and by Nov 1 it's been freezing in several years that I remember.

Comment: Another comment about the 1-day trips by car: while I have never personally driven there, I'd advise to allow plenty of time for these trips.  Road and traffic conditions make Google's driving time estimates unrealistic.  If you are thinking of hiking, you may need to be prepared for unpaved roads too.  Where are you going to be based?

Answer (score 2):

You will not be able to travel the Făgăraş Mountains in October. The Transfăgărăşan is closed due to snow so the only way to get up there and to Bâlea Lac (Bâlea Lake) is by the cable car.

The weather up in the Transylvania area will vary between cities and villages depending on their altitude but in cities like Braşov, Râşnov, and Sighişoara you can expect nice clear days. In other cities and towns like Sibiu, Predeal, Sinaia and Bran you can expect a rain shower (or a light snow) or two.

It is still a truly beautiful experience so enjoy your trip. Don't forget to try the [ţuica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C8%9Auic%C4%83).